# My mouse is detecing every button as button 1, what can I do?

Tags: 12.10, drivers, usb, mouse

I have Corsair Vengeance M60 mouse (USB), and it seems to be having issues in Ubuntu. Basically, it detects movement and detects button clicks, well, sort-of.

I put it through "xinput test" and every button I press (all of them seperately) return as being mouse button 1. So they all left click no matter what I press, and I can't remap because they all seem to think they're the same mouse button. Any ideas? Ubuntu 12.10 by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps...I am currently in the same boat sorta.  I am using the M65 on raring ringtail. works fine except for the "sniper mode" button i think that is what it is referred to as.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input

i am learning this as i go...so sorry if this didn't help.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. Please improve your answer by adding step-by-step instructions for how to configure the mouse buttons. Since you've also got a Corsair Vengeance mouse, I suggest that you write down your current mouse settings, and then test your changes on your own mouse.